# Map plugin with proximity search compatible with Buddypress

Tags: filters, search, buddypress, map

I need to be able to display Buddypress users on a map while allowing proximity/distance searches but my research yielded in plugins with subpar docs and absence of an online demo to help reassure me before I buy. Any suggestions on anything that might satisfy those criteria would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general for complicated map features I either use the [gmaps](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) API and pass the wordpress data to the initiation script via localization and `json_encode()` or the [MapPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/) plugin for simpler things.  it's highly unlikely that you're going to find something that does what you want out of the box though.